# How can I log a user's actual IP address instead of CloudFlare's?

Tags: htaccess, ip-address, logging, cloudflare

My raw access log is now filled with CloudFlare IP addresses. Is there any way I can use a *.htacess* file or configure the server to log the user's actual IP address?

With PHP, CloudFlare creates these environment variables for our reference, but I can't find anything similar for **raw access logs**.

Unfortunately, as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24348287/cloudflare-htaccess-raw-access-log%3C/em%3E) Stack Overflow question, using *mod_cloudflare.c* for the following is not an option on a shared hosting server:

```
$_ENV["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]
$_ENV["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
$_ENV["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"]
```

Answer (score 1):

We have solutions for [restoring original visitor IP](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/sections/200805497-Restoring-Visitor-IPs) with CloudFlare in our knowledge base.

Comment: Bad answer with an inaccessible link

Comment: That link loads fine for me. In addition, the server logs can only be addressed by one of the solutions in the link. Try again.

Comment: Actually see the issue(there is a weird redirect on that URL). The solutions are outlined at: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/sections/200805497-Restoring-Visitor-IPs

Comment: Yeah, link didn't work for me either, but I've edited the post with your updated one, thanks Damon.

Comment: The OP already tried _mod_cloudflare_ but can't use it on shared hosting. Unfortunately this doesn't actually answer the question of how to get these  in that case.

Answer (score 1):

> on a shared hosting server

Unfortunately, this is not possible on a shared server, since you won't have access to the server config.

To install mod_remoteip (or mod_clouldflare) and/or to change the access `LogFormat` you need access to the main server config and to be able to restart the Apache webserver.

Although with Cloudflare CDN in front of your application server, your server access logs are arguably less useful anyway, since the majority of requests are probably now served by Cloudflare.